# Kill switch in Ubuntu’s disk encryption

Tags: encryption

After just reading about a suicide switch built into kali Linux full disk encryption will it ever be possible to implement this into Ubuntu as an optionnal extra ???? Against theft like a laptop

Comment: When I concider the following link: https://www.kali.org/tutorials/emergency-self-destruction-luks-kali/  you could add this feature yourself to cryptsetup. [Or this link seems someway related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107739/how-to-trigger-a-system-self-destruct-with-a-certain-password-is-entered)

Comment: A "nuke" password wouldn't help you with a stolen laptop, since you are not there to enter it. And a self-destruction upon entering any wrong password, I'm not sure you wanna do that. A sufficiently strong password is all you really need.